# According to coding conventions, what is the space requirement for assigning variables around '='?

Tags: naming-conventions

On assigning variables I maintain only one space on each side of '=' operator. Like in the following way.

```
var $a = 1;  
var $b = 2;  
var $extra = 3;
```

But I saw my fellow programmer maintaining a tab before the '=' to make it vertical aligned. Like in the following way

```
var $a    = 1;  
var $b    = 2;  
var $sum  = 3;
```

Which one of the above is proper way to be followed and why?

Comment: In what programming language ???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no proper way to be followed. Do whatever you feel makes the code easier to read.

The only rule I'd follow is to maintain whatever conventions are already there.

Answer (score 0):

It mostly a matter of taste.  Different teams have different standards, or no standard.

Many people think that a standard is a good idea, because it makes the code consistent - there's no shifting of mental gears as you move from one developer's code to another's.

One argument for leaving only one space (or a constant number of spaces) is that you don't have to make edits to move code around when you introduce a longer variable name.  Over time, those edits can build up and get in the way when you need to look through the source control history.

Answer (score 0):

Basically the common practice is one space before = and one after.

var $a = 1;

The reason is - best readability.